# Any predefined type for unsigned 96 bit integer?

Tags: c, linux

I am working on a feature which needs to keep track of a bit-map of length 96. I use this map to program asic below.
Is there a standard integer type to hold 96 bits. For 64 bits, we have unsigned long long. Anything similar for 96 bits?
Any alternate suggestion welcome as well.

PS: This is Cisco OS based on linux. Language is C.

Comment: Why don't you simply use 3 32 bit ints?

Comment: i think the answer would be no ( because there is no existing definition), but how do i exactly look for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably go with an array of 3 uint's.  That should be fast enough, and not a lot more complex.

EG, to set a bit:

```
wordNo = i / 32
bitNo = i - (32*wordNo)
mask = 2 ** bitNo

array[wordNo] |= mask
```

...or thereabout.

Answer (score 3):

GCC has [`__int128`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) for 128-bit integers on targets that support it, but nothing for 96 bits specifically.

Comment: +1, but to be a bit more precise, gcc has that on architectures that have a native 64 bit integer type.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to create **one** variable that size is exact 96 bits: Bitfields in a union or struct.

```
typedef union { // you can use union or struct here
    __uint128_t i : 96;
} __attribute__((packed)) uint96_t;

uint96_t var;  // new uint96_t variable
var.i = 123;   // set the value to 123 (for example)
```

This worked for me with `gcc`. If you test the size of `uint96_t`  with `sizeof` you should get 12 bytes (12 * 8 = 96).

Answer (score 0):

You should use clang's new feature `_ExtInt`. It is in clang 11, so you may not have it. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61411866/11059315) for details and usage.